# ArcMap Renderer Memory Usage

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, performance, memory

I have two MXD files, both of them have one feature layer with unique value renderer and multiple values.

Symbols are completely different but all of them are approximately 500 x 500 and 72 DPI. when I open them using ArcMap their memory usage are completely different, one of them use 450 MB and the other one user 1 GB of RAM.

What exactly is happening  behind ArcMap visualization, and what parameter is affecting the memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the answer to why the memory is so different is in you saying that the:

> Symbols are completely different

To find out:

> What exactly is happening behind ArcMap visualization

I think you will need to ask Esri via their support.

Alternatively, if you want to know:

> what parameter is affecting the memory usage

then the expedient may be to experiment with those parameters and see if you can isolate what causes memory usage to increase/decrease.